# Python parse string value from xml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse the `Name` (everything within the quotes) of a xml file that looks something like this:

```
<
    ... 
    Name="Mike" 
    Phone="XXX-XXX-XXXX"
>
```

I would like to result to return `Mike`.

I am able to list the directory with `os.scandir()` like this:

```
import os
x = [f.name for f in os.scandir('/path/to/myxml')]
```

My question is, how can I parse the desired text within the xml file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1912434/62576

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Comment: xpath. Heads up though. I found I had to resort to Java because the Python support for advanced Xpath is lacking